# How to search with same value in two collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection one users and another one employees, I want to search with single keyword in first_name,last_name,email,phone_no from the first collection and employee_id,user_type_name from second collection.

I tried with the below query but it doesn't work

```
Connection.db.collection('users').aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                $and: [{
                    $or: [
                        { first_name: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') },
                        { last_name: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') },
                        { email: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') },
                        { phone_no: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'company_id': ObjectId(req.body.company_id),
                    is_deleted: 0,
                    user_type: process.env.EMPLOYEE_USER_TYPE
                }]
            }
        },

        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "employees",
                "let": {
                    eId: "$_id"
                },
                "pipeline": [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $or: [
                                        { employee_id: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') },
                                        { user_type_name: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    $expr: {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$user_id",
                                            "$$eId"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "as": "other_details"
            }
        },
        { $skip: offset },
        { $limit: perPage },
    ]).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        response = { status: status, msg: "Company user list.", data: result, total_page: total_page_number, total_record: total_record_count };
        res.json(response);
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked out [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)?

Comment: No, can you please modify the above code with $unionwith?